# CodeFirst calling stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ef-code-first

I'm using CodeFirst and the repository pattern for my program. The database I'm using as my context has a stored procedure I created and tested in SQL Server Management Studio called `dbo.sp_InsertTrackingInfo`.

In my base repository class I have

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecWithStoreProcedure(string query, int id)
{
    return _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>("sp_InsertTrackingInfo @estimate", new SqlParameter("estimate", id));
}
```

Using this query in the management studio works, where estimate is defined as an integer

```
EXEC sp_InsertTrackingInfo @estimate = '14'
```

All operations made work with the exception of this so I know I'm pointing to the right place, I've checked the SQL Server Profiler and no calls to this procedure were made at any point this function was called.

Anybody have experience with this?

Thanks,
Bmckie

EDIT:

In one of the repositories

```
using (var uow = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin())
{
    uow.EstimateTrackingRepository.Insert(t);
    uow.EstimateTrackingRepository.ExecWithStoreProcedure("exec sp_InsertTrackingInfo @estimate", t.EstimateId);
    uow.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Which code that calls `ExecWithStoreProcedure` ?

Comment: I added it to the edit

Comment: I think you need to execute the query with something like `ToArray()` after `SqlQuery` or after calling `ExecWithStoreProcedure`, does the procedure do select query after insert statement? If it's just an insert statement, probably you can just use `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: And also: it's a **stored** procedure - as in **stored** inside your SQL Server - it has nothing to do with a *store* and thus it's **not** a *store procedure* ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the procedure just does an insert statement, you can use `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

```
int rowsAffected = _context.Database
    .ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_InsertTrackingInfo {0}", id);
```

If it does a select statement, you need to execute the query, because it's a deferred (delayed) execution until *something* needs it.

```
var items = _context.Database
    .SqlQuery<T>("sp_InsertTrackingInfo {0}", id)
    .ToArray(); // or FirstOrDefault() or Any() etc
```

Comment: First one would do it. Thank you so much :)